# Factory reset has frozen

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-ace, system-freeze

My phone has recently given up and freezes on the Samsung logo screen. Having tried all the soft reset options I knew of, I have decided to wipe the data/ factory reset.

The steps followed are outlined [here](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-s5830i-galaxy-ace/) but should be pretty similar for most Samsung Android phones.

I have initiated the reset process, but now my phone has frozen on *that* too. My screen displays

```
-- Applying Multi-CSC --

-- Wiping data...
Formatting /data...
```

And what appears to be a fully-loaded progress bar (just a guess) - but that's it.

Any idea where I should go from here, as the phone's beginning to overheat so I may have to remove the battery again!

Specs: SAMSUNG S5830i Galaxy Ace

No SD card or SIM in at the moment

Comment: You should try flashing the phone, this should solve the loop. Downloaded flash files/ROM from the internet then Use Odin on a Windows computer.

Comment: How long are you waiting? This process can take 15 minutes or more, with some users reporting it takes as long as 30 minutes (it should never take longer than that).

Comment: @acejavelin I'd say at least 30 mins, but it was getting pretty warm by then, and showed no indication of progress so I switched it off. I'll try again perhaps, but I'm fairly certain it's not working as it should. I wonder if there's a test to see if it's unresponsive - like the ability to turn off the screen while the process is running (which I can't)?